# Rails wicked gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-gem

I am having problems related to the links given to login and logout.

I am not using devise gem

In my code I have given the following links

```
<% if current_user %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Logout',{:controller=>'sessions', :action=> 'destroy'}%></li>
<% else %>
  <li> <%= link_to 'Signup',{:controller =>'users', :action => 'new'} %> </li>
  <li> <%= link_to 'Login,{:controller =>'sessions', :action => 'new'} %> </li>
<% end %>
```

I am using the wicked gem which also has the following steps:

```
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :business, :login, :payment
```

If a user enters the form_for values for new method in users_controller and submits it, the user goes to the next step but the link it shows above is "Logout" i.e the user is logged in before signup.

What to do?

Pls, any solution given is appreciated

users_controller.rb:

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.update_attributes(user_params )
      session[:user_id]= @user.id
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :fname, :lname, :email, :mob, :gender, :country, :state, :suburb, :postal ,:add)
  end
end
```

user_steps_controller.rb

```
include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :business, :login, :payment

  def show
    @user = current_user
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    params[:user][:current_step] = step
    session[:user_id]= @user.id
    @user.update_attributes(user_params )
    render_wizard @user
  end

  private
  def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil)
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :current_step,:cmpyname, :abnacn, :cmpyadd, :cmpydet,:cash, :paypal,:bsb,:usrname,:password, :password_confirmation, :selcat, :protit, :prodes)
  end
end
```

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user


  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

end
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more about your multi-step form i.e the various steps you have and exactly what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: So while there is a user record you don't class the sign up as complete?  Sounds like you need a method on user (or presenter/decorator if using them) to indicate sign up is complete.  Then you can do `if current_user && current_user.sign_up_complete?`

Comment: Thanks @japed but can you give the answer to indicate signup is complete

Comment: @NitinRajan no, like Adnan said you've not indicated the steps the user must do to be classed as a complete sign up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign out the user after creating it, you can do something like this

```
if resource.save
  sign_out resource # resource = @user
```

You might need to override devise registrations controller for that if you are using devise!

EDIT:

In your `create` action you are setting session for newly created user, remove this line from your `create` action

```
 session[:user_id]= @user.id
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am not using devise

Comment: How are you handling the authentication?

Comment: i am using bcrypt @RSB

Comment: Paste your current_user method

Comment: Pasted current_user method @RSB

Comment: By removing that line i am getting "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" when i go to the next step and it is showing the error in this line ' <%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking with current_user you should check `<% if session[:user_id].present? %>`

It may solve your problem

Comment: i am not using devise

Comment: then how are you getting current_user helper method?

Comment: using bcrypt gem- @adnan

Comment: paste value of session[:user_id]

Answer (score 0):

Just check in your views if the user is logged in to show your step form:

```
<% if user_signed_in?%>
instead of 
<% if current_user%>
```